# Need help to modify java code for my requirements

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to make a bar chart in Swing and I found some code at (Demo Bar Chart in Java Swing) - 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Demobarchartandpiechart.htm

It produces three types of charts. But, I want only the bar chart without the shadows. I know very little swing so I am not able to figure out the entire code.

Please help me to remove the parts such that only i get only a bar chart without shadows.

***UPDATE***

Finally, I edited the code. Please tell me if there is any unnecessary code in it -

This is the edited code. Please tell me if there are any unnecessary code in it. I eliminated a couple of variables and also edited the import statements to make the damn thing compact.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Charts2D extends JFrame {

public Charts2D() {
super("2D Charts");
setSize(280, 280);
getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 10, 0));
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);

int[] xData = new int[8];
int[] yData = new int[8];
for (int i = 0; i < xData.length; i++) {
  xData[i] = i;
  yData[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
  if (i > 0)
    yData[i] = (yData[i - 1] + yData[i]) / 2;
}

JChart2D chart = new JChart2D(xData.length, xData, yData,"Column Chart");
GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 100, Color.white, 0, 300, Color.blue, true);
chart.setGradient(gp);
chart.setEffectIndex(JChart2D.Gradientffect);
getContentPane().add(chart);

WindowListener wndCloser = new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    System.exit(0);
  }
};
addWindowListener(wndCloser);

setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String argv[]) {
new Charts2D();
}

}

class JChart2D extends JPanel {

public static final int PLainEffect = 0;

public static final int Gradientffect = 1;

public static final int ImageEffect = 2;

protected JLabel titleLabel;

protected ChartPanel chartPanel;

protected int dataLength;

protected int[] xData;

protected int[] yData;

protected int xMin;

protected int xMax;

protected int yMin;

protected int yMax;

protected double[] pieData;

protected int m_effectIndex = PLainEffect;

protected Stroke stroke;

protected GradientPaint gradient;

protected Image foregroundImage;

protected Color lineColor = Color.black;

protected Color columnColor = Color.blue;

protected int columnWidth = 12;

public JChart2D(int nData, int[] yData, String text) {
this(nData, null, yData, text);
}

public JChart2D(int nData, int[] xD, int[] yD, String text) {
super(new BorderLayout());
setBackground(Color.white);
titleLabel = new JLabel(text, JLabel.CENTER);
add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

if (xData == null) {
  xData = new int[nData];
  for (int k = 0; k < nData; k++)
    xData[k] = k;
}
if (yD == null)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("yData can't be null");
if (nData > yD.length)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient yData length");
if (nData > xD.length)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient xData length");
dataLength = nData;
xData = xD;
yData = yD;

xMin = xMax = 0; // To include 0 into the interval
yMin = yMax = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < dataLength; k++) {
  xMin = Math.min(xMin, xData[k]);
  xMax = Math.max(xMax, xData[k]);
  yMin = Math.min(yMin, yData[k]);
  yMax = Math.max(yMax, yData[k]);
}
if (xMin == xMax)
  xMax++;
if (yMin == yMax)
  yMax++;

chartPanel = new ChartPanel();
add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void setEffectIndex(int effectIndex) {
m_effectIndex = effectIndex;
repaint();
}

public int getEffectIndex() {
return m_effectIndex;
}

public void setStroke(Stroke s) {
stroke = s;
chartPanel.repaint();
}

public void setForegroundImage(Image img) {
foregroundImage = img;
repaint();
}

public Image getForegroundImage() {
return foregroundImage;
}

public Stroke getStroke() {
return stroke;
}

public void setGradient(GradientPaint g) {
gradient = g;
repaint();
}

public GradientPaint getGradient() {
return gradient;
}

public void setColumnWidth(int c) {
columnWidth = c;
chartPanel.calcDimensions();
chartPanel.repaint();
}

public int setColumnWidth() {
return columnWidth;
}

public void setColumnColor(Color c) {
columnColor = c;
chartPanel.repaint();
}

public Color getColumnColor() {
return columnColor;
}

public void setLineColor(Color c) {
lineColor = c;
chartPanel.repaint();
}

public Color getLineColor() {
return lineColor;
}


class ChartPanel extends JComponent {
int xMargin = 5;

int yMargin = 5;

int pieGap = 10;

int m_x;

int m_y;

int m_w;

int m_h;

ChartPanel() {
  enableEvents(ComponentEvent.COMPONENT_RESIZED);
}

protected void processComponentEvent(ComponentEvent e) {
  calcDimensions();
}

public void calcDimensions() {
  Dimension d = getSize();
  m_x = xMargin;
  m_y = yMargin;
  m_w = d.width - 2 * xMargin;
  m_h = d.height - 2 * yMargin;
  m_x += columnWidth / 2;
  m_w -= columnWidth;

}

public int xChartToScreen(int x) {
  return m_x + (x - xMin) * m_w / (xMax - xMin);
}

public int yChartToScreen(int y) {
  return m_y + (yMax - y) * m_h / (yMax - yMin);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  int x0 = 0;
  int y0 = 0;

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    x0 = xChartToScreen(0);
    g.drawLine(x0, m_y, x0, m_y + m_h);
    y0 = yChartToScreen(0);
    g.drawLine(m_x, y0, m_x + m_w, y0);

  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
      RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
  g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
      RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

  if (stroke != null)
    g2.setStroke(stroke);

  GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();

    for (int k = 0; k < dataLength; k++) {
      xMax++;
      int x = xChartToScreen(xData[k]);
      int w = columnWidth;
      int y1 = yChartToScreen(yData[k]);
      int y = Math.min(y0, y1);
      int h = Math.abs(y1 - y0);
      Shape rc = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
      path.append(rc, false);
      xMax--;
    }

    if (m_effectIndex == Gradientffect && gradient != null) {
      g2.setPaint(gradient);
      g2.fill(path);
    } else if (m_effectIndex == ImageEffect
        && foregroundImage != null)
      fillByImage(g2, path, 0);
    else {
      g2.setColor(columnColor);
      g2.fill(path);
    }
    g2.setColor(lineColor);
    g2.draw(path);

}


protected void fillByImage(Graphics2D g2, Shape shape, int xOffset) {
  if (foregroundImage == null)
    return;
  int wImg = foregroundImage.getWidth(this);
  int hImg = foregroundImage.getHeight(this);
  if (wImg <= 0 || hImg <= 0)
    return;
  g2.setClip(shape);
  Rectangle bounds = shape.getBounds();
  for (int i = bounds.x + xOffset; i < bounds.x + bounds.width; i += wImg)
    for (int j = bounds.y; j < bounds.y + bounds.height; j += hImg)
      g2.drawImage(foregroundImage, i, j, this);
}
}
}
```

Comment: disable `chart.setDrawShadow(true);` ???

Comment: @mKorbel - I did all that. Disabled shadows and removed other 2 charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start removing these 2 cases from the switch and obviously remove the switch since you gonna have just one chart

```
case LineChart:
    g2.setColor(lineColor);
    path.moveTo(xChartToScreen(xData[0]),
        yChartToScreen(yData[0]));
    for (int k = 1; k < dataLength; k++)
      path.lineTo(xChartToScreen(xData[k]),
          yChartToScreen(yData[k]));
    g2.draw(path);
    break;

  case ColumnChart:
    for (int k = 0; k < dataLength; k++) {
      xMax++;
      int x = xChartToScreen(xData[k]);
      int w = columnWidth;
      int y1 = yChartToScreen(yData[k]);
      int y = Math.min(y0, y1);
      int h = Math.abs(y1 - y0);
      Shape rc = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
      path.append(rc, false);
      xMax--;
    }

    if (drawShadow) {
      AffineTransform s0 = new AffineTransform(1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
          -1.0, x0, y0);
      s0.concatenate(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1.0, 0.5));
      s0.concatenate(AffineTransform.getShearInstance(0.5, 0.0));
      s0.concatenate(new AffineTransform(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
          -x0, y0));
      g2.setColor(Color.gray);
      Shape shadow = s0.createTransformedShape(path);
      g2.fill(shadow);
    }

    if (m_effectIndex == Gradientffect && gradient != null) {
      g2.setPaint(gradient);
      g2.fill(path);
    } else if (m_effectIndex == ImageEffect
        && foregroundImage != null)
      fillByImage(g2, path, 0);
    else {
      g2.setColor(columnColor);
      g2.fill(path);
    }
    g2.setColor(lineColor);
    g2.draw(path);
    break;
```

After this, you can remove all the method/variables not used (follow the warning if you are using eclipse.)

I think you can also modify this piece of code:

```
if (m_chartType == PieChart) {
  double sum = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k < dataLength; k++) {
    yData[k] = Math.max(yData[k], 0);
    sum += yData[k];
  }
  pieData = new double[dataLength];
  for (int k = 0; k < dataLength; k++)
    pieData[k] = yData[k] * 360.0 / sum;
}

chartPanel = new ChartPanel();
add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

into:

```
if (m_chartType == PieChart) {
  double sum = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k < dataLength; k++) {
    yData[k] = Math.max(yData[k], 0);
    sum += yData[k];
  }
  pieData = new double[dataLength];
  for (int k = 0; k < dataLength; k++)
    pieData[k] = yData[k] * 360.0 / sum;
  chartPanel = new ChartPanel();
  add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: Removed the cases. No charts are shown. But, there is empty space for those charts and the titles of those charts. Working on the shadows now.

Comment: Edited my answer for another part of code you should check. Give a look to the public `JChart2D(int type, int nData, int[] xD, int[] yD, String text)`, given a tip in my edited answer.

Comment: yes, now i get only a column chart with no shadows. But the gaps between the two charts are too big and there are also no markings on the x and y axis. I want to put markings and reduce the gaps.

Comment: Have checked also `public Charts2D()`?

Comment: yes, new code is 

setSize(280, 280); - to reduce gap between columns by reducing Frame size.

and getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 10, 0));
Should have only one column, that is bar chart.

Comment: The code in your answer - if (m_chartType == PieChart) ...blah...blah.. causes an error. Its the same except a closing brace.

Comment: with the last edited part.. the code was adding a chartPanel only if it's a PieChart, if you solved in another way, you not need it.

Comment: I edited my question and added the modified code there. Please tell me if there is any unnecessary code there. Eclipse did not catch the if block that i just deleted.